# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/register.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/register.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/register.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/register.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/register.php on line 12

REGISTER.PHP

```
<?php
      $output=NULL;
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include 'config.php';

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']); //this is LINE 6
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); // LINE 7
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']); //LINE 8
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']); //LINE 9

       $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$username'";
        $result= mysqli_query($conn, $query); //LINE 12

        if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
          $output= "please all the fields";
        } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0) {
            $output= 'the username is already taken';
        } elseif (strlen($password)<8) {
            $output= "your must be atleast 8 characters";
        } else {
          // insert the record.
          $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password)
            VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$username', '$password')");

            if ($insert != TRUE) {
              $output= 'there was a problem '. mysqli_error();
            } else {
               $output= "record was successfully created " ;
            }
        }

      }


    /*if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

     $query= "INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password
              VALUES ('{$name}', '{$email}', '{$username}', '{$password}')";

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if ($result) {
          echo "user created successfuly.";
        } else {
          die ("user registeration failed".mysqli_error());
        }
      }*/
     ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>testing site</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <form method="POST">
         <table>
           <p>Fill the Registration form below</p>
           <tr>
             <td>Name: </td>
             <td> <input type="name" name="name" > </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Email: </td>
             <td>   <input type="email" name="email"> </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Username: </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="username"> </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Password: </td>
             <td><input type="password" name="password"> </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
                  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
             </td>
           </tr>

         </table>


       </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CONFIG.PHP

```
<?php
$server='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass="";
$dbname="testing";



$conn =mysqli_connect($server,$dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die ("database connection failed"
      . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_close($conn);` that's the offending line; remove it. The connection is closed, then you're trying to reuse the connection after.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Those Sharp Eyes.

Comment: thanks Fred. that worked but just to ask, how was the connection closed without using mysqli_close($conn);

Comment: @ZackZaksZaky welcome; it's inside the included directive before you queried.

Comment: Thanks once again. once trying to figure out the problem for 2 days before i asked :)